# simple multiplication arrays in java

Tags: java, loops

I want to create a simple java program only with simple loops and arrays. It should be multiplication table.

If rows are 3 and columns are 5 then, it should display rows, columns and inside the matrix it should give the multiplication of row and column. output should look like this.

```
     1    2    3    4    5
1    1    2    3    4    5
2    2    4    6    8    10
3    3    6    9    12   15
```

This i want to create with simple loops. I am new to java so I am not able to figure out how can i do this. kindly let me know.

I have done the code till here.

import java.util.*;

```
class cross_multiplication
{

    public static void main(String a[])
        {

        System.out.println("How many rows required? : ");
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num_rows = in1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many cols required? : ");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num_cols = in2.nextInt();

    //int arr1 [] = new int[num_rows]; 
    //int arr2 [] = new int[num_cols];      

        for(int i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
        {
                if (i==0)
                {
                    System.out.print("");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(i);            
                }
                System.out.print("\t");     

        }


    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: use arrays and loops THEN ask after you ahve tried

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: Not sure why you would need an array, but a simple compound `for-loop` should do the trick..

Comment: i have tried. do not please downvote. i will paste the code

Comment: @PrasadKharkar kindly check the code.

Comment: You need a second `for` loop inside the first one - using a different variable - and use it to print the product. When `i==0` you print the second control variable. You're almost there.

Comment: @sanbhat : I have updated the post with my code

Comment: @sam now that you have shown some effort - how is your code failing? Exception? Incorrect results?

Comment: @sam I hope you got your answer :)

Comment: @JanDvorak : this is just for printing row but i dont know how to print the output as shown

Comment: Damn. I have already retracted my close vote

Comment: @sam try this and let me know

Comment: A bit late - but I have added code that includes creating the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the headers, you need to check whether you are in row 0 (`j == 0`) or column 0 (`i == 0`). Example of how to do this:

```
public static void print(int x, int y) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
      if(i==0) { // first row
        if(j>0) {
          System.out.printf("%d\t", j);
        }
        else { // first row, first column: blank space
          System.out.printf("\t");
        }
      }
      else {
        if(j == 0) { // first column
          System.out.printf("%d\t", i); 
        }
        else { // actually in the body of the table - finally!
          System.out.printf("%d\t" i * j);
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
private static void print(final int[][] table){
    for(int r = 0; r < table.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < table[r].length; c++){
            System.out.printf("%d\t", table[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static int[][] table(final int rows, final int columns){
    final int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
    for(int r = 1; r <= rows; r++)
        for(int c = 1; c <= columns; c++)
            array[r-1][c-1] = r * c;
    return array;
}
```

From the code above, if you want to print the 10x10 multiplication table, you could do this:

```
print(table(10, 10));
```

And the output will look something like this:

[image: 10x10 output]

Comment: Now we just have to add the headers back in...

Comment: @Floris Surely the OP will be able to add in the headers himself.

Comment: I didn't say you had to do it for him. Hence the "we have to add", rather than "hey Josh, you forgot the headers". Learning by doing...

Comment: @Floris : sorry but i do not understand what you said.

Comment: @sam - in your original "desired output" you had a separate row above the table to indicate one factor, and a column to the left of the table as well. The code that Josh helpfully provided doesn't include those "headers". I am sure you can figure out how to add them (your code snipped in the question already prints out the header of the top row... now you just need an `if(i==0)` type statement to print the first column. Make sense?

Comment: @Floris : yes. i got u now. thanks for making me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

im not going to give you the answer but i will give you some pseudocode

You did correctly set up 2 loops

```
Loop x = 1 to 3
    Loop y = 1 to 3
        //Do stuff
    End innerloop
End outerloop
```

This will print all your solutions in a straight, single line. But you want it to be in a matrix obviously. The answer is to simple a simple change, taking only one line of code. After each full cycle of your inner loop, you essentially finish one row of multiplication (think about why). So the solution is that after your inner loop finishes running, right before going to the next outer loop value for x, you want to print a new line. All in all we have something like:

```
Loop x = 1 to 3
    Loop y = 1 to 3
        z = x * y
        Print z + " "
    End innerloop
    Print NewLine // "\n" is the way to do that
End outerloop
```

and try out

```
public static void print(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++) {

            System.out.print(" " + i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```